# Deserialize multiple nested Entities with Symfony 4

Tags: xml, symfony, nested, entity, serialization

Lets say I have this XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Order>
  <InvoiceNumber>201902130420</InvoiceNumber>
  <Products>
    <Product>
      <Name>DaVinci IQ</Name>
      <SKU>420342300</SKU>
    </Product>
    <Product>
      <Name>Mighty</Name>
      <SKU>420342305</SKU>
    </Product>
  </Products>
</Order>
```

and want to deserialize the given XML into an existing "Order"-Entity, containing a set of Product-Entities with all subnodes of <Product> in the Order's property $products.

When I call

```
$order = $this->serializer->deserialize($xmlContent, Order::class, 'xml');
```

I do get an Order-object with the parameters from the XML and my $products-property gets filled with array items.

However, while I would like to have a set of Product[]-Entities in my resulting Order-Object, my $products-property gets filled with a flat array containing the product values instead.

In other words: I would like the resulting $order to look like this:

```
App\Model\Order {
  -InvoiceNumber: "201902130420"
  -products: array:2 [
    0 => App\Model\Product {
      -Name: DaVinci IQ
      -SKU: 420342300
    }
    1 => App\Model\Product {
      -Name: Mighty
      -SKU: 420342305
    }
  ]
}
```

But I get this instead:

```
App\Model\Order {
  -InvoiceNumber: "201902130420"
  -products: array:2 [
    "Product" => array:2 [
      "Name" => "DaVinci IQ"
      "SKU" => "420342300"
    ]
    "Product" => array:2 [
      "Name" => "Mighty"
      "SKU" => "420342305"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Can anyone help out?

Answer (score -1):

Does your Serializer have the ArrayDenormalizer loaded ? If so, it should work if you call it like this :

```
$order = $this->serializer->deserialize($xmlContent,'App\Model\Product[]', 'xml');
```

Notice the [] after the class name.

Edit: Put in the class path App\Model\Product, didnt see that before :-)

Comment: Not what he asked.

Comment: I just noticed... you are right, sorry! 

Problem is probably that the products property is probably not correctly annotated as Product class in the Order model. That explains why it is serialized as array.

But we need to see the Order model class to help further.